# can I pass json object from controller to view without any request from view?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I'm working on a asp mvc web application and I want to let user to see changes from other users without refreshing the page . 
so , I tried sending request by ajax in an interval to check if there's any update in my database in last n seconds . this is my code :

```
 function checkForNewMsgs() {
            requestData = {
                id: 1
            }
            $.ajax({
                url: "/user/message/checkForNews",
                type: "POST",
                dataType: 'json',
                contentType: "application/json",
                data: JSON.stringify(requestData),
                success: function (response) {
                    if (response != "no news") {

                        }
                    }
                }
            });
        }
```

so it works fine but there's a problem here , I send an ajax request to my server in every 10s in order to check for news , I want to ask you , is there any way to send json object from controller to view whenever it was needed ? 
as an example , send for my user a message when another user send it to him , not to check every 10s for new messages . I'm not sure if my question was clear or not ! :) 
thank you all

Comment: Use [SignalR](https://www.asp.net/signalr)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are different ways to accomplish this task: 
* you can use SignalR to have an online connection from web page to back-end. 
* you can use Not-Modifid Http header to reduce traffic

better approach to solve this problem is using Js libraries such as React and Angular to interact with back-end code.

Comment: thanks for your answer , I searched about SignalR and found it suitable for my webapp